# Selecting or copying a line in Kile

Tags: kile

Is there a fast way in Kile to select or copy a whole line?
Ideally, I'd want to do it with a single keyboard shortcut.

Comment: With three keys: "Pos1/Home" -> "Shift"+"End".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First way for whatever command you can imagine**

In the menu 'Settings --> Configure kile -(tab)-> Editing` is a "Vi input mode" tab that contains checkboxes. By checking "Use Vi input mode" you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> and use whatever vi command you like... and they are really many. (The one you want is "yy"). Then leaving Vi input mode with the same button combination you can paste with the default or your changed keyboard shortcut. You also can change the commands but haven't succeed on that yet.

**Second way easy for your command**

You can go to Settings--> Configure kile ->Editing-(tab)->General and check the box "Copy/Cut the current line if no selection".

Then a simple <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> inside the line gives you your desired result.

Comment: The second thing works well. The first is not convenient for this specific thing, as it pastes on the same line, maybe isn't copying the newline character.

Comment: I tested the first too, but is somehow complicated if you don't know how exactly to do it. With the compination above you are in vi edit mode and can copy all the line until the newline. I am in vi mode there is a way to paste exactly as you wish... But it takes some effort until get used to vi commands for everyone. You can search for whatever command you need in vi mode and sure there is a way to do everything.

Comment: A similar feature that I would really want, is what you have in Visual Studio code, that every time you press Ctrl + i it selects the line after the lines already selected (selecting the current line when nothing is selected).

Comment: @relG: Try my first way. Edit vi mode (Ctrl+Meta+v) press V (capital) to select first line and use down arrow to go to next line(s)... Then get out of vi mode (Ctrl+Meta+v) and copy with Ctrl+c ... paste with Ctrl+v... etc...

Answer (score 0):

If you look under Edit --> Select, you'll find that a keyboard shortcut for selecting a line exists already:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd>.

(I.e. press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, release, then press <kbd>L</kbd>.)

If you wish to change that, you can to so under Settings --> Configure Shortcuts.

Comment: That shortcut doesn't work. And in configure shortcuts I don't see a 'select line'.

Comment: @relG Perhaps we have different versions, I'm on 2.1.3. What does it say in Edit --> Select? And in Configure shortcuts, the name of the shortcut is just "Line", not "Select line".

Comment: @relG I for example see this in that menu: http://imgur.com/a/5JRjx, and that shortcut is found again in the configuration: http://imgur.com/a/HexXm (number three from the top under the "Kile" heading).